# Returning an int if a record is found or a false if data isn't found

Tags: c#, return-type

I've got a method that gets a grade from a table for a student. If there are no records (null result set) then it should return false.

Do I write a function that returns a boolean (is found, is not found) and an integer as a reference parameter?

This is what I have so far (I return a -1 from the proc if the record isn't found)

```
public static int getParticipationGrade(SqlConnection sqlConn, int enrollmentID)
{
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_participation_byEnrollmentID_Select", sqlConn);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enrollmentID", enrollmentID);

    int ret = 0;
    sqlConn.Open();
    ret = (int)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    sqlConn.Close();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Yes, an `int` as a `ref` parameter makes sense -- it would be fairly analogous to `Dictionary.TryGetValue`.

Comment: does it HAVE to return `false` if there is no record? can the calling method check for a -1 return value?

Comment: Hi, not related to your main question... you can put the declaration of the SqlCommand in a using statement and you can create a command simply doing sqlConn.CreateCommand :)

Answer (score 8):

I would return int? where null meant not found.

```
public static int? getParticipationGrade(SqlConnection sqlConn, int enrollmentID)
{
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_participation_byEnrollmentID_Select", sqlConn); 
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enrollmentID", enrollmentID); 
    int ret = 0; 
    sqlConn.Open(); 
    ret = (int)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar(); 
    sqlConn.Close(); 
    return ret < 0 ? (int?) null : ret;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the best choise.

Comment: How would I have to change my code to do that? Would the local int have to also be int?

Comment: @Caveatrob Not necessarily, but you have to ensure that the method returns a nullable `int`.

Comment: Why create a nullable reference to an `int`? Use the `out` param modifier as we see in so many Microsoft classes, e.g. `Dictionary.TryGet()` - as @Luke suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code as the example, I would do something like:

```
public bool TryGetParticipationGrade(SqlConnection sqlConn, out int enrollmentID)
{
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_participation_byEnrollmentID_Select", sqlConn);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enrollmentID", enrollmentID);

    sqlConn.Open();
    enrollmentId = (int)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    sqlConn.Close();
    return enrollmentId != -1;        
}
```

Usage:

```
int enrollmentId;
if (TryGetParticipationGrade(sqlConn, out enrollmentId))
{
    // perform success tasks
}
else
{
    // perform fail tasks
}
```

Comment: +1 because the method follows the practice of the `Dictionary.TryGet()`. I personally like this better than creating a nullable reference to an `int`.

Comment: Okay so the proc should return -1 if not found. Gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the method return an `object`, then test to see what the type is, but that isn't generally a good idea.  What would probably be better would be to return a nullable int `int?`, then check the `HasValue` property.  Have the method return null if nothing is found, and return an integer if it is found.

Comment: I almost downvoted this when I read the first line. You might reverse the order in which you make recommendations. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax of "GetParticipationGrade" implies that its return value should be the grade itself. It seems to make sense to return an invalid value, such as -1 or NULL (as per the other answers, and that would be my choice as well*), and then check to ensure the grade is valid.

That's all convention, of course, but you'd only expect a Boolean return from a method like `TryParse()`, for example.

**To explain, I would prefer `int?` to a sentinel grade like -1, because nullable value types are built (`HasValue` property) for the sort of check you want to do.*